# How to add clarity to a declarative sentence?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, sentence, business-language

I have the following sentence, and I am wondering how I could make it more clear, and catchy because i feel like there is something wrong with it. Does the message come across properly?

> Apprentices inject enthusiasm, hard work, and a thirst for knowledge
>   into your teams.

Comment: Could you provide more context? What's the business domain here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like what's wrong with this sentence is the figurative use of the word *inject* with *hard work* and *thirst for knowledge.* Do you mean apprentices contribute or inspire hard work? *Thirst* is particularly confusing--what does it mean to inject thirst? Thirst is generally something that arises as a result of the absence of a actual or metaphorical nutrient. Maybe you mean that apprentices' thirst for knowledge drives a team to seek answers. This sentence is an example of how metaphorical language can cloud an author's meaning where more concrete language would be clearer.